# Can't ssh to my Ubuntu VM

Tags: ssh, vmware

I'm currently running Ubuntu in a VMworkstation Pro, when I try to SSH into it, the connection is rejected. But, I can ping Ubuntu IP successfully.

Comment: `ssh -v theServer` will show more information.

Comment: have you enabled openssh-server? (sshd)  a default install sets up ssh only for outgoing, not incoming.

Comment: No not specifically. I'm new to all of this. How do I check or start the openssh server.

Comment: I'm using Putty from my Windows 10 laptop to ssh to the Ububtu VM.

Comment: `sudo apt install openssh-server`    ssh on Ubuntu largely refers to the client software which allows you ssh TO another box. sshd/openssh-server is the system daemon or server part of it which allows ssh INTO the box.  (specifying version of Ubuntu may help - my answer is consequentially generic)

Answer (score 2):

You need to start and enable (so that it runs on system startup) the SSH server:

```
sudo systemctl enable ssh.service
sudo systemctl start ssh.service
```

Comment: I got it working. Needed to install the package. Thx for the help.

Comment: @ClydeB If this answer helped you, please check the mark (left hand column) and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to install openssh-server package using the following command:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server -y
```

Make sure to activate the service and check if it really is:

```
sudo systemctl start ssh
sudo systemctl status ssh
```

To be sure that it is enabled at boot, execute the following command:

```
sudo systemctl enable ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect from a Windows 10 machine, then Microsoft SSH may be getting in the way.  You need to change the port in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` in the VM to something other than `22`.  For example, if you choose `2222`, then you would tell putty to also connect to port `2222`.